# How to use into and to

Tags: prepositions

Which of the following is a correct sentence:

1. By his wrongdoing, he brought the institution to disrepute.
2. By his wrongdoing, he brought the institution into disrepute.

Answer (score 2):

"[Bring/brought **into** disrepute](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bring%20into%20disrepute)" (link to Merriam–Webster) is the correct idiom here.

Comment: Also in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/into-disrepute-in-disrepute)